# html2canvas 0.5.0 beta2 input bug

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

Recently I`ve started to use html2canvas.js and faced the problem: input element with button type isn't rendering correctly. I'm new at programming, so I don't know how to fix it by myself. Here is plunker with the bug: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U5VuRgcTHji7apJ5tKft?p=preview)

index.html:

```
<div id="button" class="index_search">
    <input type="button" value="Search">
</div>
<div id="renderedButton"></div>
```

script.js:

```
window.onload = function () {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('button')).then(function (canvas) {
        document.getElementById('renderedButton').appendChild(canvas);
    });
}
```

I also attached stable 0.4.1 version of html2canvas (html.js).
Help please :)

Comment: See this comment on a similar issue reporting. This is from 2011, but I think the main problem is still the same : https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2#issuecomment-1637196

Answer (score 0):

Different implementations in browsers how form elements should look like (tablet/pc's/mobile phones/future proofing) combined with that it is a bad practice to style form elements means this will probably never be supported by the library.

You can solve this though by making your own styled button which does not use an input tag. For example a div with a border and gradient will quickly make it look exactly like a regular button.